# Creating a table of city distances

Tags: python, r, distance

I have a list of about a hundred of cities and wonder is there an automatic way to get a table 100 x 100 where in cells I would have Euclidean distances between cities, given column and row. So, it would be a triangular matrix (upper, lower, does not matter), like in this example (taken from `R` package `psych`):

```
     ATL  BOS  ORD  DCA
ATL    0  934  585  542
BOS  934    0  853  392
ORD  585  853    0  598
DCA  542  392  598    0
```

I know about several packages i `R` that maybe could do this (like, `gmapsdistance`, `gdistance`, `ggmap` etc.), and I guess there is something convenient in `Python` as well, but any code example would be much appreciated. Also, I think that Google API would not work since it would give a travel, not Euclidean if I'm not mistaken. Thanks!

Comment: You say that you have "a list of cities"  do you just have the names of the cities or do you have some information like lat-lon from which distance could be calculated?

Comment: This may be a job for [Haversine formula](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/haversine)